# Problem in using if statement in a function

Tags: javascript

I am facing a simple problem while using an if statement in a function.

This code is functioning properly:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Typewriter</h1>

<button onclick="typeWriter()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
var speed = 50;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

but when i declare the variables inside the function it keeps on repeating the first letter of variable text. Why does that happen?

Here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Typewriter</h1>

<button onclick="typeWriter()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>


function typeWriter() {

var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
var speed = 50;
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do on your second code?

Comment: It's because of  var i =0 ;

Comment: I want to get the same output from both the codes, but why is the first letter of var txt repeating when I have declared the variables inside the function.

Comment: you might check the set time out being called repeatedly.

Comment: Yeah, but in both the cases we have put i = 0 and we are incrementing it by 1, then why isn't it giving the same result?

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: setTimeout() is calling  typeWriter function in each iteration.

Comment: @sanchitarora The answers posted here explain the difference between local vs global variables. If you go through this concept, it would surely help you.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring a local variable "i" inside typeWriter() function which creates a local context, and this "i" variable is initialized to 0 every time typeWriter() function is called. When the variable is declared outside, it is part of global context, but in your second case, variable "i" is in local context.

Edit:
Debug both code line by line and you will know which version of variable "i" maintains the last value and which one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are recalling the `typeWriter` function every time `typeWriter` runs in your `setTimeout` (which allows you to loop). Thus, you are reinitializing (overring the value of) `i` to `0` every loop/function call.

However, in your first example, your variables are global, and so they do not get reinitialized each time you recall the `typeWriter` function. This allows your [recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) to eventually meet its *base case* and terminate. Whereas in example two, this doesn't happen as `i` will always be `0` when the function runs.

Instead, you can consider using local arguments if you wish to keep the variables local:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Typewriter</h1>

<button onclick="typeWriter('Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.', 0)">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var speed = 50;
function typeWriter(txt, i) {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    setTimeout(_ => typeWriter(txt, ++i), speed);
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

**It's because of var i =0; inside the function.**

Every time you call the function it sets value of i back to zero which causes to print only the first character to printed on screen. In order to avoid this you define the counter outside the function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Typewriter</h1>

<button onclick="typeWriter()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var i = 0;
function typeWriter() {
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
var speed = 50;
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```